# What order to use for serverless.yml plugins?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

What should be the correct order of arranging these plugins for serverless.yml? I am using serverless to deploy my express app to AWS lambda

Plugins:

- serverless-plugin-common-excludes
- serverless-plugin-include-dependencies
- serverless-esbuild
- serverless-plugin-package-size
- serverless-bundle
- serverless-offline
- serverless-dynamodb-local
- serverless-dotenv-plugin

I have found order for `serverless-plugin-common-excludes` and
`serverless-plugin-include-dependencies` plugins on serverless website.

Comment: I am using expressJS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.